# Video stuttering in webview on Android?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, webview, android-webview

I am developing an app which displays a webview of a webpage which displays 1080p videos in a slideshow. For some reason I cannot make the video play smoothly in webview. If I play the same video in an app like Kodi or VLC it plays very smoothly. The device itself can handle up to 4K videos.
But a simple short 1080p video is stuttering badly when played in android webview.

The app is developed in Flutter, and I have tried both `flutter_webview_plugin` and the stock `webview_flutter` with the same result.

I also have `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

The device is a TV box with Amlogic S905X2 (4x Arm Cortex-A53 @ 1.80 GHz + Mali-G31 MP2 + 4GB RAM) which has hardware that should easily handle this. The videos are in MP4 format and small, plays nicely everywhere else.

What else can I try?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using a webview to load video instead of playing video directly on Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to play video on a WebView instead of natively in Flutter. But here's an example of streaming video directly in Flutter using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  bool _playing = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network("https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/005/621/original/Coffee_Smokey_BRoll.mp4");
    _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Video player'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _videoPlayerController.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
              )
              : Container(),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () => _playing ? pauseVideo() : playVideo(),
                  icon: _playing ?  Icon(Icons.pause): Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  label: _playing ? Text('Pause') : Text('Play')
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  void playVideo(){
    _videoPlayerController.play();
    setState(() {
      _playing = true;
    });
  }

  void pauseVideo(){
    _videoPlayerController.pause();
    setState(() {
      _playing = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I wasn't sure if when you said a Slideshow you meant the video was a of a slideshow, or you wanted several slides each playing videos.

Comment: Thanks for the response @João. The reason for webview is that I have developed a multi platform service which displays a slideshow of pictures and videos. They play in webview as the content is served from the website. And it can be mixed and matched with pictures, which makes it very hard to do with the video player, if I don't want to create a specific solution for each device. Is there a reason why webview performs much worse with video playing? I mean a simple budget laptop can handle it with Chrome, why wouldn't a modern mobile CPU handle this?

Comment: Most WebViews across iOS and Android don't perform very well. They are very different from a modern browser and definitely not as optimized. If you application is just a wrapper of a web page, maybe you can try running an experiment with doing a web wrapper app directly on Android. There are plenty of tutorials online on it. This way you can compare the performance of a native webview vs the webview through flutter, and conclude if the problem is Flutter or just playing videos on webviews.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried a web wrapper on android with the same result. Also using Chrome on the device stutters playing video. The least stuttering is Firefox. So there's something not optimized correctly. But the device does handle everything perfectly except this. Also tried on an android phone and tablet. Same thing.

Comment: Like I said. Webviews are not the same as standard browsers. You will find that there are many differences in not just performance but also how javascript is handled and other things. If you want to give a good user experience to your users, try learning Flutter a bit more and get your data from your API and use it natively to play videos and show your content. I'm sure it would be great.

Comment: Is there any alternative to webview, where you can get the same performance of a real browser without redesigning everything I have already made?

Comment: Alternative like a different kind of webview? No.